# Boolean parameter passes to widget as null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing `true` to a widget to calculate the border radius of a button. For some reason `round` passes as `null` and the ternary in the next simplified code returns 25. What am I doing wrong?

```
CustomButton(
   height: 60.0,
   round: true,
);
```

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({
    @required this.height,
    this.round,
  });

  final height;
  final round;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return CustomElevation(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(round == true ? height / 2 : 25),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First off, `round == true` is precisely the same as just `round`.   Next, you should probably add a "bool" annotation to the round var.  Then also realize if that widget is rebuilt, I'm not sure `round` is keeping its value, unless you put it into a stateful widget's state.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I am not rebuilding it if I understand you right, just intializing 1 time. None of other things helped, for some reason `round` is `null`.

Comment: try to chenge cond to round? height / 2 : 25 and declare final bool round before constructor

Comment: @John Where did you define height ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja did not work

Comment: @MidhunMP it was simplified code, I edited it now. The thing is - height passes ok and `height / 2` by itself works like expected. But `round` passes like a `null`. I even tried it with integers and doubles.

Comment: @John I tried your code and it's working perfectly fine. Only thing was I've to specify types for that round and height (bool, double respectively). Just restart the app and check once again

Comment: @MidhunMP did `flutter clean`, restarted my PC, deleted previous version from my phone. Still `round` is `null`.

Comment: Why not ```final bool round;```?

Comment: @John Just print the value of round in the build method and check. I don't see any issues in your code.

Comment: @ikerfah I came from dynamically typed languages and experementing to write in a such way. I tried changing it to `final bool round` and it did not help.

Comment: @MidhunMP did it, prints out `null`.

Comment: Are you using Android studio ? try File-> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @ikerfah I am using VS Code. I think `flutter clean` should've cleaned all the needed cache there. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomButton(
   height: 60.0,
   round: true,
);
```

> First off, round == true is precisely the same as just round. Next, you should probably add a "bool" annotation to the round var. Then also realize if that widget is rebuilt, I'm not sure round is keeping its value, unless you put it into a stateful widget's state ([mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618010/boolean-parameter-passes-to-widget-as-null#comment116015147_65618010))

> Second, try using null-type safe, so it prevents nullability

> Third, if a parameter request double value, use double value, not integer

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({
    @required this.height,
    this.round,
  });

  final double height;
  final bool round;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return CustomElevation(
      child: RawMaterialButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular((round ?? false) ? height / 2.0 : 25.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```